# call method not using current assigned object data to public function

Tags: javascript

Actually I'm studying on apply, bind and call.  To test them out, I simply created one simple function as below.

```
var data = [{
  "option": "com_easysocial",
  "userId": localStorage.getItem("ckuser"),
  "layout": "getConversations",
  "view": "conversations",
  "format": "json",
  "limit": 2
}];

var Data = data['layout'];

function ajaxCall(arrayOfdata){
    var score = arrayOfdata;
    return score;
    this.Data = score['layout'];
}
/***global variable & functions end***/

var contacts = {
   data : [{
      "option": "com_easysocial",
      "userId": localStorage.getItem("ckuser"),
      "layout": "getContacts",
      "view": "conversations",
      "format": "json",
      "limit": 1
    }],

    Data: null
}

console.log(ajaxCall(contacts.Data));//null
ajaxCall.call (contacts, contacts.data);
 console.log (window.Data); //undefined
 console.log (contacts.Data); // null
```

for this `console.log (contacts.Data)` aftfer the `call` usage. I expected, for the Data inside ajaxCall function to store the data sent from `contacts`object thus display 'getContacts' for the layout. But it displays null. Which means it still uses Data inside contacts. Also for window.Data it returns undefined. I expected getConversations. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Your ajaxXall function returns before it stores anything. Whenever you use `return`, nothing after that line *(in that scope)* is executed-

Comment: Updated the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method:

```
function ajaxCall(arrayOfdata){
    var score = arrayOfdata;
    return score;
    this.Data = score['layout']; // nothing will execute below the return statement.
}
```

is returning before `this.Data` is set..

You need this:

```
function ajaxCall(arrayOfdata){
    var score = arrayOfdata;
    this.Data = score['layout'];

    return score;
}
```

#### Calling `this.Data`

I would be careful defining global variables and referencing them in functions.

`this.Data` might refer to a `this` that isn't the window scope...

You're leaving it up to the person who is calling the method to pass in a scope then, which is not ideal. It is better to just work with return values, or create class structures.

#### console.log(contacts.Data) returns undefined, why?

Actually, if you look:

```
var contacts = {
   data : [{
      "option": "com_easysocial",
      "userId": localStorage.getItem("ckuser"),
      "layout": "getContacts",
      "view": "conversations",
      "format": "json",
      "limit": 1
    }],

    Data: null
}
```

`contacts.data` is an array, so

```
function ajaxCall(arrayOfdata){
    var score = arrayOfdata;
    this.Data = score['layout']; // score here is an array

    return score;
}
```

Here you see score is an array, you're trying to access with a string key rather then doing something like:

```
this.Data = score[0]['layout'];
```

Comment: console.log (contacts.Data);  returns undefined..why? after changing the function as per yours

Comment: @Keren because you've set `Data: null` in contacts object. Notice the 'data' and 'Data'. you're passing `Data` not `data`.